# Installing Packages using python in Virtual Environment in Linux(Bash to Python )

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I am creating a virtual environment and installing packages. In shell script, i can able to install all the packages. But in my python code, getting **Permission denied** error message while installing `pytest`, `pytest-cov`, etc.

**Shell Code**

```
VIRT_DIR=virt_folder
pip install --user virtualenv
virtualenv $VIRT_DIR
. $VIRT_DIR/bin/activate
pip install pylint
pip install coverage
pip install pytest
pip install pytest-cov
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

**Python Code (Version 2.7)**

```
VIRT_DIR = "virt_folder"
subprocess.call("pip install --user virtualenv", shell=True)
subprocess.call("virtualenv " + VIRT_DIR, shell=True)
subprocess.call(". " + VIRT_DIR + "/bin/activate", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install pylint", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install coverage", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install pytest", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install pytest-cov", shell=True)
```

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Post the whole error message with full traceback please

Comment: Posted the error message.Thanks .

Comment: `virtualenv`'s `activate` works on the shell level within the same shell process, while `subprocess.call` spawns a new process, thus whatever environment variables that were set will not be reflected in that Python process, hence the virtual environment **cannot** be activated from within the same Python process.

Comment: Each `subprocess.call(…, shell=True)` creates a whole new subshell. So, dotting the venv `activate` script doesn't do anything useful; it just activates it for that particular shell, which immediately closes. Then the new shell for the next command is back in your normal environment, and trying to install globally.

Comment: Also, you can't really activate a virtualenv effectively from within Python—even if you did manage to select a different Python interpreter, that wouldn't change the fact that you're in the middle of running the previous one. At best you could confuse things by mixing modules from two different stdlib and site-packages directories.

Comment: Can i know how to perform this functionality using python code.

Comment: I replaced "subprocess.call(". " + VIRT_DIR + "/bin/activate", shell=True)" with "
activate_this = (VIRT_DIR + "/bin/activate_this.py")
 execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__= activate_this)) "

It worked